# I installed Ubuntu 11.10, and it took over my number 2 drive d: which was a music directory

Tags: uninstall

c: drive has XP PRO 32 BIT.  I made one 65gb partition on c: which was named L: drive.

I was hoping to install Ubuntu on the partition, but I made mistakes and lost all of d: drive and Ubuntu also grabbed L: drive.

I want to first see if I can recover as much of my music as possible. And then uninstall Ubuntu from the d: and re-install it to the L: partition on c: drive.

I need help with all of the questions I have typed.  I know nothing about Ubuntu, that is why I was trying to install it.

Can I do any of the questions I have asked.

rod

Comment: I think this question is abandoned and could be closed

Answer (score 0):

I could not understand first that how could you make a partition inside a partition when a operating system is installed on that. I mean isn't it like cutting the branch of tree on which you are sitting. But above all, only recovering your data matters here first. So let me be clear. 
If you have completely wiped of all your data, then it is possible to recover some part of it(as they have traces on magnetic tape surrounded on hard disk sectors). Since you are using windows, So I would recommend you to use some window based recovery application. ["Easus get data back"](http://www.easeus.com/data-recovery/other-recovery-software/get-data-back-ntfs.htm) is the one for you to recover the data. But music is the thing that you can grab easily from the internet. Then Just try to install ubuntu in a separate partition as further you might mistakenly loose c: drive and then you could not even start an OS.

Answer (score 0):

**First of all: use the affected PC as little as possible!** Every write access on your overwritten HDD could erase a little of your music library. If you are on this PC now reading this, shut it down! Boot this PC only from live CDs!

Secondly, what you will have to do in order to recover your data is not so easy ... so if you think you can't do it and you know a PC expert or something you should ask him/her for help. And don't panic! When you work this out slowly and carefully, there might be much to recover.

You should make an entire backup of your D: drive **ASAP** from which you could restore files later. When your Ubuntu installation erased the D: partition completely it may be best to backup the entire HDD.
To do that, you need a external or internal (**not the one your D: partition was on**) HDD which has enough free space and a Ubuntu Live CD. Everything you have to do is described here: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/19446/make-a-drive-image-using-an-ubuntu-live-cd/

After that you can relax because you have now an image of your HDD to work with and no more files are lost from now on.

There are now two ways I know to rescue your music:

ddrescue (free, linux, command line, all file names are lost): http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html

If your D: drive happened to be an NTFS drive I strongly recommend that you use `Get Data Back for NTFS` for Windows - it's not free to get but it worked like a charm for me, with folders and file names recovered): http://www.runtime.org/data-recovery-software.htm
(I'm not sure if NTFS Recovery works with DD Images but you could let it work with your overwritten partition too)

IF you're D: partition is totally overwritten by Ubuntu,**I think** you have to recreate the overwritten partition table in order to rescue your files. you can try that with Testdisk (it's also free and on the [Knoppix recovery CD](http://www.knoppix.org/)): http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step